# How can i make this encrypt-er Loop back the alphabet?

Tags: java

For a project at school, im doing a Cesar Cypher Encrypter. I only have one problem, when i want to encrypt Z, it goes to {, not A. How can i fix this? Thank you so much.

//code for anyone interested.(Inputs are stored into the charArray and switched to ASCII numbers.)

```
int difference = charArray[i] - 61;
                int toSubtract = key - difference;
                int newCharacter = 91 - toSubtract;
                int a = newCharacter;
                char b = (char) a;
                System.out.print(b);
```

Comment: First, normalize the letters - 'A' = 0...'Z' = 25. Then add the key. Next, use the '%' operator with 26 to handle the overflow. Then convert back to a letter - 'A' = 65...'Z' = 90.